# Mapbox-js-gl Not Showing Raster Tiles

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Here is my tile template

```
https://public-tiles.dronedeploy.com/1483655752_DANIELOPENPIPELINE_ortho_oet/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9wdWJsaWMtdGlsZXMuZHJvbmVkZXBsb3kuY29tLzE0ODM2NTU3NTJfREFOSUVMT1BFTlBJUEVMSU5FX29ydGhvX29ldC8qIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNDg2NDE2NjE2fX19XX0_&Signature=edPjUkREQB6pgv~VBJVkI4CgZI673ahY6UfEdVtkJu-SnnNCKNcWwpsbtOTjgbaCEw0zCsn625XSSXUMRGqTGdTjn36Z1haKMkX6tnW-EqggCkcH52h0kkWUM6gXclIaXsQNlUwTVe5AczE687WovEf4b1iAHbYefHt-FLxEY91ZUltbzIhh850LoW4mSMxRd691oSKqXfVzgJHZv8CHENk26D1BRuU3cDiY2khXPnEtHLC-~vz3bqNrOpdc0Al-D-Khz4ZXtOUxCwkT9U8dKU0o0a8pxT15rQSA6ocWo5eS5gHpk0HulxaD840rV6Sn8uju13Xjt3ob1UCqJkyt5g__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJXGC45PGQXCMCXSA
```

And if you replace /{z}/{x}/{y}/

It does render an image.

```
https://public-tiles.dronedeploy.com/1483655752_DANIELOPENPIPELINE_ortho_oet/17/31400/48592.png?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9wdWJsaWMtdGlsZXMuZHJvbmVkZXBsb3kuY29tLzE0ODM2NTU3NTJfREFOSUVMT1BFTlBJUEVMSU5FX29ydGhvX29ldC8qIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNDg2NDE2NjE2fX19XX0_&Signature=edPjUkREQB6pgv~VBJVkI4CgZI673ahY6UfEdVtkJu-SnnNCKNcWwpsbtOTjgbaCEw0zCsn625XSSXUMRGqTGdTjn36Z1haKMkX6tnW-EqggCkcH52h0kkWUM6gXclIaXsQNlUwTVe5AczE687WovEf4b1iAHbYefHt-FLxEY91ZUltbzIhh850LoW4mSMxRd691oSKqXfVzgJHZv8CHENk26D1BRuU3cDiY2khXPnEtHLC-~vz3bqNrOpdc0Al-D-Khz4ZXtOUxCwkT9U8dKU0o0a8pxT15rQSA6ocWo5eS5gHpk0HulxaD840rV6Sn8uju13Xjt3ob1UCqJkyt5g__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJXGC45PGQXCMCXSA
```

But when I use mapbox-gls `tiles: []` it loads the images but does not render them to the map.

Below is the code I'm using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.30.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.30.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGFuaWVscmFzbXVzb24yIiwiYSI6ImNpajM3anR2ODAwNGJ1eGtuNXFtbXhqMTMifQ.u3dqaFnALVDcqWyGu6Oq-w';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', // container id
  center: [-93.75562777777778, 42.13104722222222], // starting position
  zoom: 15, // starting zoom,
  style: {
    "version": 8,
    "sources": {
      "raster-tiles": {
        "type": "raster",
        "url": "mapbox://mapbox.satellite",
        "tileSize": 256
      }
    },
    "layers": [{
      "id": "simple-tiles",
      "type": "raster",
      "source": "raster-tiles",
      "minzoom": 0,
      "maxzoom": 22
    }]
  },
});

map.on('load', function(){
  map.addSource('dronedeploy-tiles', {
    "type": "raster",
    "tiles": ["https://public-tiles.dronedeploy.com/1483655752_DANIELOPENPIPELINE_ortho_oet/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9wdWJsaWMtdGlsZXMuZHJvbmVkZXBsb3kuY29tLzE0ODM2NTU3NTJfREFOSUVMT1BFTlBJUEVMSU5FX29ydGhvX29ldC8qIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNDg2NDE2NjE2fX19XX0_&Signature=edPjUkREQB6pgv~VBJVkI4CgZI673ahY6UfEdVtkJu-SnnNCKNcWwpsbtOTjgbaCEw0zCsn625XSSXUMRGqTGdTjn36Z1haKMkX6tnW-EqggCkcH52h0kkWUM6gXclIaXsQNlUwTVe5AczE687WovEf4b1iAHbYefHt-FLxEY91ZUltbzIhh850LoW4mSMxRd691oSKqXfVzgJHZv8CHENk26D1BRuU3cDiY2khXPnEtHLC-~vz3bqNrOpdc0Al-D-Khz4ZXtOUxCwkT9U8dKU0o0a8pxT15rQSA6ocWo5eS5gHpk0HulxaD840rV6Sn8uju13Xjt3ob1UCqJkyt5g__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJXGC45PGQXCMCXSA"],
    "tileSize": 256
  });

  map.addLayer({
    "id": "dronedeploy-tiles",
    "type": "raster",
    "source": "dronedeploy-tiles",
    "minzoom": 0,
    "maxzoom": 22,
    'layout': {
      'visibility': 'visible'
    },
  });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting 403 errors even on the link you posted that is supposed to return an error. It looks like that endpoint doesn't have 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header that it needs to allow requests from arbitrary domains.

Comment: I think the authentication expired. :/

Comment: What is the server you are using to serve the tiles? Or are you not the one serving the tiles?

Comment: Ok yeah, now I'm seeing the images. You have to enable CORS on your S3 bucket.

Comment: O interesting, thanks for the comment @mollymerp. The tiles work with leaflet, I'm guessing that is because map-box-gl is using xhr to load the images while leaflet simply loads them through html. Does that sound correct?